# IPP patched ZLIB missing symbols

Tags: zlib, intel-ipp

I patched ZLIB 1.2.11 using IPP 2016 (and 2019), all went fine, all compiled fine (using MSVC). But linker comes with following missing symbols (I added all necessary libs, and I actually tried adding all libs from IPP at all)

```
1>zlib_x32_debug.lib(deflate.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ippsDeflateLZ77FastestGetStat_8u referenced in function _custDeflateUpdateTable
1>zlib_x32_debug.lib(deflate.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ippsDeflateLZ77Fastest_8u referenced in function _lz77_encode_call
1>zlib_x32_debug.lib(deflate.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ippsDeflateLZ77FastestPrecompHeader_8u referenced in function _lz77_encode_call
1>zlib_x32_debug.lib(deflate.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ippsDeflateLZ77Fast_8u referenced in function _lz77_encode_call
1>zlib_x32_debug.lib(deflate.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ippsDeflateLZ77Slow_8u referenced in function _lz77_encode_call
1>zlib_x32_debug.lib(deflate.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ippsDeflateLZ77FastestGenHuffTable_8u referenced in function _zzdeflateGetTabLen
1>zlib_x32_debug.lib(deflate.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ippsDeflateLZ77FastestGenHeader_8u referenced in function _zzdeflateGetTabLen
```

Then I even tried to search the libs for these symbols and they are nowhere to be found... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please, check that you link proper IPP library bit version to your object files. I mean, 32-bit libraries should be linked to 32-bit object files. Looks, like "zlib_x32_debug.lib" is a 64-bit static lib (and linker looks for 64-bit variant of functions). As far as I remember, 32-bit functions have object files names like "blabla@number" and 64-bit functions are named as "_blabla".

Comment: It turns out it is some kind of mismatch between the 2 IPP versions I have installed here, not sure about the details yet.

Comment: These functions appeared in IPP library starting from version 2017. Not in 9.0 or earlier versions.

Comment: Exactly! But I was actually trying to link it against the stuff in IPP 2019 and it didn't work. Then I used IPP without year number and it started working :). No idea, probably the symlinks were incorrectly assigned to 2016 version...